# Find specific node to uninstall a module

Tags: nodes, installation

I want to uninstall a module but I'm getting the following message. The "Name of Module" field type is used in the following field: node.field_feature_interest. How can I find this node so I can remove their relationship between each other so that I can delete the module?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it:

1. Go to content types
2. Features Article ->Manage Fields
3. Delete field